# Out of memory when activating UI Game Object in device (Android)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-development

We are developing a mobile game using Unity 2019.2.17f1. There is a bug that happens only when we test the game on a physical Android device, but not on all devices. Sometimes, when activating certain UI Game Objects, the game simply hard crashes. Upon inspection of the logcat output we get this:

```
    Trying to allocate: 8388609B with 16 alignment. MemoryLabel: Texture
    Allocation happened at: Line:78 in 
    Memory overview

    [ ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD ] used: 35494B | peak: 0B | reserved: 2850816B 
    [ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB_1_FRAME ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 11534336B 
    [ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB_2_FRAMES ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 1048576B 
    [ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB_4_FRAMES ] used: 0B | peak: 0B | reserved: 2097152B 
    [ ALLOC_TEMP_JOB_ASYNC ] used: 6019860B | peak: 0B | reserved: 14680064B 
    [ ALLOC_DEFAULT ] used: 119089062B | peak: 126982715B | reserved: 121770988B 
    [ ALLOC_GAMEOBJECT ] used: 1456307B | peak: 1456307B | reserved: 1582524B 
    [ ALLOC_GFX ] used: 657024804B | peak: 657024804B | reserved: 657035387B 

     #0 0xc0ad1055 (libunity.so) ? 0x0
     #1 0xc09d027b (libunity.so) ? 0x0
     #2 0xc05923c9 (libunity.so) ? 0x0
     #3 0xc05909f9 (libunity.so) ? 0x0
     #4 0xc0590d01 (libunity.so) ? 0x0
     #5 0xc0590cad (libunity.so) ? 0x0
     #6 0xc06444c5 (libunity.so) ? 0x0
     #7 0xc04ec069 (libunity.so
```

I checked the textures in the game and there seems to be no problems with them. I attempted to set them all to 512 in size (along with the Atlas), but The problem persists. The error is relatively quiet log-wise, Unity doesn't even output anything. This only happens to three maybe four Game Objects. For interface we're using the standard Unity RectTransforms on a Screen Space Overlay Canvas. We tried a new Unity version (2019.3) but it didn't help either.

Comment: Have you tried making a memory snapshot on one of your crashing devices and look at the texture allocations in it specifically to see which one might be causing the issue?

Comment: [Akın Erkan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11802078) wanted to know "Did you check setpass calls and drawcalls ?". They wanted "clarification for what happens to see in editor when UI elements enabled. I thought it might be melting resources when UI objects enabled" from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61572081/12695027)

Comment: @Remy I will look into how do to that, I suppose. I'm not experienced with this kind of debugging so it may take a while, but I will get back to you with my findings. However, I have tried disabling/enabling several textures to try and narrow down the issue in a more of a trial and error fashion, but I couldn't pin one down. It seems like it's not ONE particular texture.

Comment: in that device what is the memory size?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar, one of the devices is a Samsung S10+. It should have more than enough memory.

Comment: your sprite is static? / can you try deleting  GI Cache ? / try Build Settings and make sure Scripts Only Build is unchecked   /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up finding the problem using the Unity Profiler. The problem is that the error wasn't caused by an IMAGE texture, but by a font. For some reason the font is super heavy when it loads. Replacing the font solves the issue.[image: Unity profiler showing the cause of the issue]